# How to draw boxplot by creating age buckets from integer age entries

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data frame in R, an example of which is given below:

```
age     number_of_visits 
19            10
50            24
25            50
24            35
31            19
42            26
55            40
64            15
20            35
67            20
69            18
33            15
28            50
62            18
```

I need to create age bins like 18 to 24, 25 to 39, 40 to 54, 55 to 65, and above 65, and then for each of these age bins I need to create boxplots for number of visits.

It would be helpful, if any one can provide code to be used in Rstudio
Thank you!

Comment: Please show what you have already tried and why it has failed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `cut2` from the `Hmisc` package:

```r
library(Hmisc)

# Toy Data
age <- rnorm(100, mean=45, sd=15)
number_of_visits <- rnorm(100, mean=20, sd=10)

# cut2 lets you set custom cutpoints
interval <- cut2(age, c(18,25,40,55,65))

boxplot(number_of_visits ~ interval)
```

[image]